# CircleCI/Github pull request status not showing

Tags: github, circleci

Not entirely sure if this is an appropriate place for this question but I'd like to get my pull requests to show the status of the CircleCI build but can't find any solid documentation on it. The two are integrated and the builds start running as soon as a PR is created. I found some docs that said I should go to Settings > Branches and then request that status checks pass before merging, but there are no options for CircleCI listed. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CircleCI Discuss](https://discuss.circleci.com) would be the best place but I can try to answer here.

My first suggestion would be to redo the webhooks. By unfollowing and refollowing the project. This isn't the same issue but troubleshooting steps would be similar to: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/workflows-waiting-status/